# Processing each row in column

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

1. I'm trying to go through each row in column 'birth'
2. Check if the last part of the string separated by "," ends in two characters
   2.a. If it does, I will append "US" to it.

So, "Los Angeles, Ca" would be "Los Angeles, Ca, US"
And "Bisacquino, Sicily, Italy" would stay the same

I want to process this in a function.

I've tried this but when checking checking the length of birthStr it gives me the length of all the rows

```
for row in subset.itertuples():        
   birthStr= subset['birth'].str.rsplit(",", 1).str[-1]
   if len(birthStr) ==2:
      subset.birth = birthStr + "," + "US"
```

Comment: you should not iterate over the dataframe using `itertuples`, it should be a last case resort

Comment: Add some sample data and expected output to this question.   May like 5 to 10 examples mixed with those that need US and those that don't.

Comment: In addition to what @aws_apprentice stated, check what is returned by `itertuples()`, and how many input variables you're iterating over in your function

Comment: see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/2327328) about making good pandas examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the `str` methods provided by `pandas` to solve for this. Let's use the following dataframe that I define below.

```
print(df)
                       place
0            Los Angeles, Ca
1  Bisacquino, Sicily, Italy
2               New York, NY


condition = df.place.str.split(',').str[-1].str.strip().str.len() == 2

df.loc[condition, 'place'] = df.place + ', US'

print(df)

                       place
0        Los Angeles, Ca, US
1  Bisacquino, Sicily, Italy
2           New York, NY, US
```